# Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) to serve php and Nginix or Tomcat to serve jsp/Servlets

Tags: apache, jsp, servlets, nginx, tomcat7

I'm running Ubuntu on a VPS with a LAMP stack, with Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu 10.04) installed with various Virtual Hosts.
This current setup is running two different sites on two domains and this is working fine.
However I now need to install some servlet container (nginx or Tomcat or Resin) to run JSP/Serverlets on a third domain.

All three domains runs as virtual hosts on the same VPS (same IP).

I'm looking for a way to run both html/php and jsp/servlets with as little resource consumption as posible?